# query get every last date on a month

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table like this

| date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 100 |
| 2021-01-15 | 200 |
| 2021-01-31 | 300 |
| 2021-02-01 | 400 |
| 2021-02-15 | 500 |
| 2021-02-28 | 600 |
| 2021-03-01 | 700 |
| 2021-03-02 | 800 |
| 2021-03-03 | 900 |

and i want create a report like this

| date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-31 | 300 |
| 2021-02-28 | 600 |
| 2021-03-03 | 900 |

I confused how create a query to provide data like that, get amount every last date on a month.

Let's say I put an amount on 4 march 2021 the report will show data like this

| date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-31 | 300 |
| 2021-02-28 | 600 |
| 2021-03-04 | 1000 |

I am using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cbc61c878b827fe9b4568594498da9ed)

To find the most recent record of a group you can use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('month', my_date))
    *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', my_date), my_date DESC
```

1. `date_trunc('month', ...)` normalizes a date to the first of a month. So every date within February will be converted to `'2021-02-01'`. This can be used for a group of months
2. Ordering these groups by their actual `date DESC`, which orders the most recent date to the top of the month group. `DISTINCT ON` returns exactly this records.

Comment: added explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with row_number() :

```
**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

CREATE TABLE tablename (
    date date,
    amount int
);

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES
('2021-01-01',  100),
('2021-01-15',  200),
('2021-01-31',  300),
('2021-02-01',  400),
('2021-02-15',  500),
('2021-02-28',  600),
('2021-03-01',  700),
('2021-03-02',  800),
('2021-03-03',  900),
('2021-03-04',  1000);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select date,amount from 
(
  select date,amount ,
  row_number()over (partition by (extract (year from date)),(extract (month from date )) order by date desc)RN
       from tablename
)T
WHERE RN=1;
```

| date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 300 |
| 2021-02-28T00:00:00.000Z | 600 |
| 2021-03-04T00:00:00.000Z | 1000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Since same month can exist for multiple year in real data I have used year and month together for partition by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_trunc('month', date + '01 Months'::interval) - '01 Days'::interval, sum(amount) 
from tableName
group by date_trunc('month', date + '01 Months'::interval) - '01 Days'::interval
order by date_trunc('month', date + '01 Months'::interval) - '01 Days'::interval desc
```